# Override a:hover with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have defined an `<a>` tag with css. I'm trying to stop default stylesheet `:hover` changes on the `a` tag. How do I disable the hover changes on the a tag in Jquery?

Answer (score 13):

Live demo of the following solution: http://jsbin.com/umiru

--

The easiest way I can think of is to change:

```
a:hover { ... }
```

into

```
a.someClass:hover { ... }
```

And then add/remove `.someClass` via jQuery's methods:

```
$(this).addClass("someClass");    // activates css rules for :hover
$(this).removeClass("someClass"); // deactivates css rules for :hover
```

Comment: Do you mean your stylesheet has `a:hover { color:red }` or something similar?

Comment: zsharp - the solution I provided works. Please see the link included at the top of my solution for a demonstration.

Comment: This a brilliant idea! Thank you! You can add !important to make sure that style styles the document.

Answer (score 6):

Here is a solution without hack classes:

CSS:

```
a {color: blue;}
a:hover {color: red;}
```

jQuery (uses [jQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/) to animate color):

```
$('a').hover( 
  function() {
    $(this)
      .css('color','blue')
      .animate({'color': 'red'}, 400);
  },
  function() {
    $(this)
      .animate({'color': 'blue'}, 400);
  }
);
```

[demo](http://jsbin.com/udahe3/2/edit)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to create a new CSS rule for the specific a tag. Something like

```
a.linkclass:hover {color:samecolor}
```

If you have to use JQuery to override the default styles, you have to manually add the css rules in the hover state, something like this:

```
$('a.linkclass').hover(function(){
    $(this).css({'color':'samecolor'});
});
```

hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Just define your CSS without a "a:hover"

```
a { color: #fffff }
```

This CSS will override the a:link, a:hover, a:visited and a:active.