# CSS id selector not working

Tags: jquery, css, css-selectors

I'm trying to make some hover actions using jQuery, but I think the selector isn't working. Here's the HTML:

```
<div id="footer">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Start a Something</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Send a Gift</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">How It Works</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Secure Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About Company</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>

            <ul>
                <li>&copy; 2012 Company</li>
                <li><a href="#">Terms of Use and Privacy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

And here's the jQuery:

```
$('#footer ul li').mouseover(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color: "white"
        }, 200);
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(this).animate({
            color: "#bcbdbd"
        }, 200);
});
```

What selector should I be using?

Comment: Looks valid to me, maybe you need to wrap everything on `document.ready`

Comment: -1 define "not working" and summarize it in the title; e.g. does `$(the_selector)` return a set of 0 elements or ..?

Comment: Wrap with document.ready and $('#footer ul li a') to make the selector work, but still you can't animate color.

Proof that it works: http://jsfiddle.net/Mhp2c/10/
To animate color, check out http://motyar.blogspot.se/2010/07/animate-color-using-jquery.html

Comment: Your question has an answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7516407/jquery-animate-text-color)

Answer (score 5):

Why oh why are you using jQuery for this task?

RAW CSS!

```
#footer ul li a { /* or even just "#footer a" */
    color: #bcbdbd;
    transition: color 0.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: color 0.2s ease;
    /* Chrome does not yet support the un-prefixed version */
}
#footer ul li a:hover { /* same comment as above */
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: Granted, IE 9 and below will just see an abrupt colour change, but such a minor aesthetic difference is no excuse for using jQuery for the most mundane of tasks ;)

Comment: 0.2s TRANSITION NO WORK IN IE6 NOT GUD ENUFF. `=]`

Comment: On a less ironic tone, I agree that catering to old browsers for such minor progressive enhancement is a waste of time for the developer (and some microseconds performance loss for end-users?).

Comment: I used transitions initially but IE9 incompatibility bothered me too much. :P

Comment: Upgrade to IE10, then. It's out for Windows 7 and it works tremendously well.

Answer (score 3):

```
$('#footer ul li a').hover(...
```

They're links so color on the `<li>` won't change them.

Comment: Yup, I know. Tried changing the color to be under that selector in my CSS, but it didn't make the jQuery code work.

Comment: If you're going with a jQuery solution, it'd be much more efficient to use the `.hover()` method ;)

Comment: You're totally right, I was just changing the selector but I should have added that as well.  Post edited.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using:

```
$('#footer ul li a');
```

Your selector isn't wrong, but you should be applying those actionhandlers and animations to the `<a>` tags instead.

adjusting color in the wrapping `<li>` won't override the color that was default with the `<a>` tags

**EDIT:**

As to the answer of what you want to achieve, you will have problems trying override the CSS :hover with JQuery alone. But JQuery UI employs http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.cssHooks/ in their animate() http://jqueryui.com/animate/

Using that, using animate on .hover() or .mouseover() will override the default CSS :hover properties to use the JQuery's animate.

Example:
http://jsbin.com/udahe3/399/

Answer elsewhere on SO: [Override a:hover with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053693/override-ahover-with-jquery)

Comment: Tried it, didn't work. In my CSS I'm using color on the ul li a, too.

Answer (score 1):

You could target the **A** element instead:

```
$('#footer ul a')
```