# Assign a:hover to dynamically loaded content with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css

I have a page that load contents using

`$('#header').load('head.html')`, but the links inside head.html cannot use my website.css because website.css loaded earlier or for another reason.

so  I thought this `$('a:hover').css('color','green');` but no success.

I can solve with  tags but I dont want to do it.

Update:

---

**base.html**

```
<script> 
    $('#header').load('/restaurant{{ chosenRest }}.html'); //chosenRest=1,2..etc
</script>

<div id="accordion">
<div id="header" >   </div></div>
```

I have files like, restaurant1.html, restaurant2.html

---

**restaurant1.html**

```
<a href="/Giorgio"> Giorgio's </a>
```

---

**website.css**

```
a:hover {color:green};
```

---

now if I add something like `<style> a:hover {color:green; } </style>` to **base.html** it works, but I don't want to do that way.

**update: Finally Solved**

here what worked:

**base.css** I added a new class

```
.restaurant:a:hover {
      color:green;
}
```

**restaurant1.html**

```
<a href="/Giorgio" class="restaurant"> Giorgio's </a>
```

Comment: css has no issue with time of loading so it should use website.css and however by jquery `$('a').hover(function(){$(this).css('color','green');},function(){$(this).css('color','prev_one');});`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you add pseudo classes to elements using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12740967/how-do-you-add-pseudo-classes-to-elements-using-jquery)

Comment: Check your `CSS`. probably you have something like `#body a:hover{}` then you load your a in `#header`. Post `CSS` here for more info.

Comment: CSS will be applied even to elements added after the page is loaded. There is something else going on, does your head.html contain an iframe or something funky like that? Can you post the contents of the head.html ?

Comment: @narek I checked I only have `a:hover {color:green;}`

Comment: @jbl The jquery here is confusing, but not really essential to the question. Not a duplicate (at least not of what you linked)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053693/override-ahover-with-jquery is very relevant I think, I will implement that solution if I cant find any better.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/narekmarkosyan/F8MYx/1/ as you can see here link hover works on delayed loaded html. Problem in your `HTML/CSS` structure. If you post it here answer will be found fast and **witout** jQuery.

Comment: thanks @Narek, it makes clear sense, I think there may be difference between .load vs .html, I am preparing a jsfiddle now.

Comment: Problem is what you cant add load in jsfiddle, because loaded file need to be on the same domain, but as I know load get data from addres and make `$().html()` so in jquery level it's same.

Comment: @Narek both points are right, when I tried to add your .html() code, it did not work either. So I think there is a more general problem, I ll paste in a bit all the structure.

Answer (score 2):

Use `.on()` with the `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events and delegate the events:

```
$(document.body).on('mouseenter','a',function()
 {
  $(this).data("oldcolor",$(this).css('color')); //Store old color
  $(this).css('color','green');
 }).on('mouseleave','a',function()
 {
  $(this).css('color',$(this).data('oldcolor')); //retrieve old color
 }
)
```

Use `data()` to store the old color

---

Alternatively, you can do this with vanilla JS:

```
 document.styleSheets[0].insertRule('a:hover { color: green; }', 0);
```

Or, just add  `a:hover { color: green; }` to a stylesheet, but you may not want to do that (this will be there from the start, whereas via JS you can choose when to add the rule)

Comment: -1 Plain CSS does this much better. And should work. The question is not about event handlers (as far as i can tell)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'data' ` ,`Uncaught TypeError: Object [object HTMLAnchorElement] has no method 'css'`

Comment: @xec: Added alternate way.

Comment: @EmmetB: Fixed, sorry about that.

Comment: @xec: Which is why I gave my last solution. It depends if he wants control on when the rule is applied or not.

Comment: @Manishearth actually your second solution works. But it works only for changing background-color, not the color. Any idea?

Comment: @EmmetB: My mistake, fixed

Comment: @Manishearth that is what I was trying to say: background-color works, but color does not work.

Comment: @EmmetB: that depends on the rest of your stylesheet. You may need `!important`

Answer (score 0):

Probably **CSS doesn't load** when you make `load`.
just add `DOM ready` for your load.

```
<script> 
$(function(){
    $('#header').load('/restaurant{{ chosenRest }}.html'); //chosenRest=1,2..etc
});
</script>
```